# Eddystone UID - Android Optimal FavIcon

Tags: favicon, beacon, eddystone

I have Eddystone UID functioning correctly for nearby Android phones who have Bluetooth enabled. In other words, a notification appears in the notification window with a brief call to action (or as specified) along with the favicon pulled from the linked website. The issue is that the favicon is very low resolution. The icon that's being pulled is obviously not optimal and is being blown up to fill the notification window.

What is the preferred favicon format for these display windows to show the icon in optimal resolution? I have seen them displaying correctly with high resolution icons, so I know that it can be done.